# Add includeExceptionDetailInFaults

Tags: web-services, exception, web-config

Trying to add `includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"` to web config for web service that I am calling but none of two behaviors that I have defined are working.

This is the error I get when calling web service:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process
>   the request due to an internal error. For more information about the
>   error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the
>   server in order to send the exception information back to the client,
>   or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK
>   documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="debug">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<!--<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="debug">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>-->

<client>
  <endpoint address="..."
            binding="wsHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICommunicationService"
            behaviorConfiguration="debug"
            contract="CommunicationServiceReference.ICommunicationService" 
            name="WSHttpBinding_ICommunicationService" />
</client>
```

EDIT: 
I looked at this similar question, but in suggested answer there is

```
<services>
      <service...
```

while in my case it's

```
<client>
  <endpoint
```

I also tried changing to `services` but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you're including the attribute at the wrong end, basically you're telling the client to include exception information (which would be a security risk).

In the service web.config you will have a section for behaviours (this is taken from our code which is working fine and has done for about 4 years):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings configSource="bindings.config"></bindings>
    <client configSource="client-local.config"></client>
    <behaviors configSource="behaviors.config"></behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="xxx.SomeService">
        <endpoint contract="xxx.ISomeService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding"/>
      </service>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Behaviours.config looks like this:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Also, by externalising the config we can keep one copy in a _MasterConfigs folder that is copied to the services at build time which ensures consistency across all projects.

**EDIT:**
Apologies... I just re-read your question and you've basically got what I've outlined. Perhaps the fact you're naming the behaviour is causing the problem (not that it logically should). Unless it's a publicly exposed WCF I think it best to return exception information anyway, even in release, for logging.